# Decrypt with jasypt after retrieving the encrypted value in Http Request

Tags: java, http, url, encryption, jasypt

I am having problem to make work jaspyt in this scenario:

```
StrongTextEncryptor textEncryptor = new StrongTextEncryptor();      
textEncryptor.setPassword("myPassword");
String myEncryptedParam = textEncryptor.encrypt("myClearMessage");

myObject.setCallbackUrl("http://myhost/notification?myparam="+myEncryptedParam);
```

When I receive the callback url and try to decrypt the param 'myParam' provided in the url WITH THE SAME STRONGTEXTENCRYPTOR used in the request, it raises an exception:

```
org.jasypt.exceptions.EncryptionOperationNotPossibleException
at org.jasypt.encryption.pbe.StandardPBEByteEncryptor.decrypt(StandardPBEByteEncryptor.java:1055)
at org.jasypt.encryption.pbe.StandardPBEStringEncryptor.decrypt(StandardPBEStringEncryptor.java:725)
at org.jasypt.util.text.StrongTextEncryptor.decrypt(StrongTextEncryptor.java:118)
at com.softlysoftware.caligraph.util.Util.decryptMessage(Util.java:30)
```

Digging a bit more in the exception I get:

```
BadPaddingException: Given final block not properly padded
```

If I test the encryption/decryption process without httprequest, works ok.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `StrongTextEncryptor` uses `StandardPBEStringEncryptor` which in turn uses Base64 to encode the ciphertexts. The problem is that Base64 has a `/` character which is not URL-safe. When you try to decrypt, the parameter parser that you use probably drops those `/` characters which makes the ciphertext incomplete.

The easiest solution is probably to change the offending characters with replace all:

```
myEncryptedParam.replaceAll("/", "_").replaceAll("\\+", "-");
```

and back again before you try to decrypt:

```
receivedParam.replaceAll("_", "/").replaceAll("-", "\\+");
```

This transforms the encoding from the normal Base64 encoding to the ["URL and Filename safe" Base 64 alphabet](http://tools.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4648.txt).

Answer (score 0):

Building on Artjom's answer, here is a Jasypt text encryptor wrapper

```
import org.jasypt.util.text.TextEncryptor;

public class UrlSafeTextEncryptor implements TextEncryptor {

    private TextEncryptor textEncryptor; // thread safe

    public UrlSafeTextEncryptor(TextEncryptor textEncryptor) {
        this.textEncryptor = textEncryptor;
    }

    public String encrypt(String string) {
        String encrypted = textEncryptor.encrypt(string);

        return encrypted.replaceAll("/", "_").replaceAll("\\+", "-");
    }

    public String decrypt(String encrypted) {

        encrypted = encrypted.replaceAll("_", "/").replaceAll("-", "\\+");

        return textEncryptor.decrypt(encrypted);
    }
}
```

and corresponding test case

```
import org.jasypt.util.text.StrongTextEncryptor;
import org.jasypt.util.text.TextEncryptor;
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;

public class UrlSafeTextEncryptorTest {

    private String password = "12345678";

    protected TextEncryptor encryptor;
    protected UrlSafeTextEncryptor urlSafeEncryptor;

    @Before
    public void init() {
        StrongTextEncryptor encryptor = new StrongTextEncryptor(); // your implementation here
        encryptor.setPassword(password);

        this.encryptor = encryptor;

        this.urlSafeEncryptor = new UrlSafeTextEncryptor(encryptor);
    }

    @Test
    public void scramble_roundtrip_urlSafe() {

        int i = 0;
        while(true) {
            String key = Integer.toString(i);

            String urlSafeEncrypted = urlSafeEncryptor.encrypt(key);

            Assert.assertFalse(urlSafeEncrypted, urlSafeEncrypted.contains("/"));

            Assert.assertEquals(key, urlSafeEncryptor.decrypt(urlSafeEncrypted));

            if(urlSafeEncrypted.contains("_")) {
                break;
            }

            i++;
        }

    }
}
```